# How can I create an Excel formula that will look up value on a different sheet?

Tags: excel

What commands do I use in my formula, so that I can look up a value on another sheet. In other words, how do I put make the formula look up sheet1 range `L2:L37`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND("SA64",L2:L37))))
```

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND("SA64",Sheet1!L2:L37))))  brain went dead this is what I WAS TRYING TO DO

Answer (score 0):

I know it's obvious, but I wanted to post an answer so that the answer can be marked as resolved and if for any reason another user has the same issue they can locate the answer.

**Answer**:
To reference another sheet before a range, simply put the sheet name, followed by !

```
Ex: Sheet1!L2:L37
```

While typing the formula, you can select the sheet and the cell/range and Excel will add the sheet name for your automatically.